# Javascript: Stop Auto-refresh Function by a Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I am constructing a webpage with an auto-refresh function in every 1 minute. Also, my webpage include a auto-refresh ON and OFF button for the users to choose whether to turn on/off auto-refresh. By default, the webpage will auto refresh now once its load.

However, I would like to let's user to turn off the auto-refresh function if users do not want to turn on the function. I tried to search for the answer and some people said that it can use `clearTimeout(timeout)` function. Hence, **I would like to know how to stop auto-refresh function by clicking an OFF button**? Is it by adding `clearTimeout(timeout)` code into Javascript? Thank you.

The code for auto refresh function:

```
    <body onload="setInterval(reloadPage, 5000);">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function reloadPage(){
      var refreshEnabled = document.getElementById('auto-refresh-checkbox');
      if(refreshEnabled.checked) {
        window.location.reload(60000);
      }
    }
    </script>
```

The code for turn ON/OFF button:

```
<div class="page-header-actions" data-toggle="buttons" role="group">
  <label class="btn btn-outline btn-primary active">
    <input id="auto-refresh-checkbox" type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off" value="autorefreshon" checked />
    <i class="icon wb-check text-active" aria-hidden="true"></i> Auto Refresh ON
  </label>
    <label class="btn btn-outline btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off" value="autorefreshoff" />
    <i class="icon wb-check text-active" aria-hidden="true"></i> Auto Refresh OFF
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but If you would use `setTimeout` you could cancel it with `clearTimeout`. If you use `setInterval` you have to cancel it with `clearInterval` instead. You have to add a listener to the radios so you detect when the user selects them and cancel the interval or start it again depending on the radio value. If you need further assistance please provide your tests in a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Remove onload and put setinterval in [document ready function](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(fname, 10000);
```

/* later on click of button or */

```
clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
```

See the docs for [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) and [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval).